# How to setup Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-core

I'm an MSDN subscriber. I would like to install Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core, but when I insert MSDN #4629 DVD there're only full versions of Windows Server 2008 R2. **How am I supposed to install Server Core then?** Any suggestions? Is it possible to covert it back to server core when a GUI version's already installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same media.  As part of the install process you're prompted to select the edition.

[Check this out for screen shots](http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-install-windows-server-2008-step-by-step.htm)

[image]

revert to core after an install?  doubt it very much.

Comment: Strange. No such choices for me. The strangest thing was also that I wasn't presented with a choice about hard disk... Changed media with MSDN downloaded DVD image. Everything worked. I had Server core choices and all. It finally worked.

Comment: One more clarification. I have choices for full installation but not Server Core ones. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the wrong CD, sounds like a Retail CD (for installing your customers' servers).

Go to the [MSDN Subscriber's Downloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx), Under Operating Systems, pick Server 2008 R2. The second download in there is for DVD 50365, you'll find keys as well so you can run it for more than a week.

There's no way to switch from Core to Full or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the software do not use a product ID - leave the box blank. At that point you will be asked which version of the software to install - Core is one of the options.

Comment: The MSDN version doesn't ask for the Product ID or Key or any of that. It just shows the license agreement, lets you pick a version, and installs.